# AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django 1.5 on Python 3.2.3.

When I run `python3 manage.py syncdb`, it builds the DB tables, & asks for my email (defined as the unique instead of a username), and then when I enter that, I get this error --

`AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'`

Oddly, it creates the tables anyway, but now, I'm confused 'cause I really don't get what I'm supposed to do. The documentation says I should create a [Custom User Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager), but that's all it really says. It doesn't give me a clue where to create it or how. I looked through the [docs on Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/), but that really didn't help me figure anything out. It's all too vague. I keep Googling trying to find some clue as to what I need to do, but I'm just going crazy with more and more questions instead of any answer. Here's my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class MyUsr(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True,db_index=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    pwd_try_count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pwd_last_try = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    resetid = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    last_reset = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    activation_code = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fname','activation_code']
```

How do I write a Custom User Manager? Do I put it in the MyUsr model as a method? Or is that even what I'm supposed to do? Should I be doing something totally different? I'm not sure of anything at this point. I just don't understand. The documentation on this doesn't seem clear to me, leaving a lot open for interpretation. I'm pretty new to Django, but I've  been into Python for several months.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You define a custom manager by sub-classing **BaseUserManager** and assigning it in your Model to the **objects** attribute.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager

class MyMgr(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(...):
        ...

    def create_superuser(...):
        ...


class MyUsr(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = MyMgr()

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

You must define the `create_user` and `create_superuser` methods for your `BaseUserManager`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/).

Comment: Thanks! This problem was driving me up a wall for a while. Couldn't find a clue wherever I looked.

Comment: If you directly subclass `UserManager` you already have these methods implemented! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#manager-methods

Comment: @Caumons Your comment is very helpful! Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your case all you might need to fix this error will be to assign the `objects` variable in the `CustomUser` class, to inherit form `BaseUserManager()` instead of `models.Manager()` which some would have initially set

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    ......
    # model managers
    # objects = models.Manager()
    objects = BaseUserManager()
```